# Search dictionary by dictionary

Tags: python, dictionary, search, find

I have two dictionaries:

```
v = {'name': ['Peter', 'Paul', 'Mary'], 'city': ['London', 'Rome', 'NY'], 'country': ['GB', 'I', 'USA'], 'age': ['30', '35', '45']}

d = {'city': 'Rome', 'country': 'I', 'age': 35}
```

I'd like to get `Paul` returned if I search `v` for the exact values from `d`.

Do I have to 'nested loop' through all the possibilities or is there an easy way like

```
if all of d anywhere in v.rows:
    print(v[name])
```

Comment: Why are you using a dictionary of lists instead of a list of dictionaries?

Comment: Your current data structure doesn't lend itself to that kind of search.

Answer (score 0):

Loop through the `name` element, and compare the corresponding elements of the other lists with the `d` values.

```
found = None
for i, name in v['name']:
    if all(v[key][i] == val for key, val in d):
        found = name
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you have same length,

```
for i in range(len(v['name'])):
    #compare all the other details and print the name
    if d['city']==v['city'][i] and d['country']==v['country'][i] \
        and d['age']==v['age'][i]:
        print(v['name'][i])
```